# log4j configuration error

Tags: log4j, slf4j

When I am debugging my code then It goes to hibernateUtil which I make after it show a following error

```
og4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.gidiserver.util.HibernateUtil).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.8 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.debug(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.register(BasicTypeRegistry.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.<init>(BasicTypeRegistry.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeResolver.<init>(TypeResolver.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:302)
    at com.gidiserver.serviceimpl.GidiBrainServiceImpl.displaySubjectDetails(GidiBrainServiceImpl.java:554)
    at com.gidiserver.serviceimpl.GidiBrainServiceImpl.main(GidiBrainServiceImpl.java:2194)
```

Comment: provide code snippet where you are initializing your log4j. If you are using xml configuration file for log4j, provide this file contents.

Comment: The link telling you what the problem is is actually **right in the message**: http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch
Take care of the slf4j version mismatch first, then worry about the log4j configuration (which isn't the cause of the error, as it's just a warning).

Answer (score 0):

Just adding sheltem's comment as an answer:

> The link telling you what the problem is is actually right in the message: slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch Take care of the slf4j version mismatch first, then worry about the log4j configuration (which isn't the cause of the error, as it's just a warning).

After that, if you still want to use log4j as the slf4j binding (instead of [logback](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping)), add a either a log4j.properties in `src/test/resources` (this is all assuming you're using maven or gradle), or `{module}-log4j.properties`, and defining this properties file as your logging config in the surefire plugin, e.g., a system property in pom.xml (assuming maven):

```
<log4j.configuration>${project.artifactId}-log4j.properties</log4j.configuration>
```

Answer (score -1):

Put [log4j.properties](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/) in to  `src/main/resources`.

Comment: That only pertains to the warning, not the error (which is slf4j related, not log4j); also, don't put log4j.properties in the main/resources directory, otherwise it'll be bundled with the app. For testing, provide logging configuration in src/test/resources, preferably naming the file something other than the default, e.g., module-log4j.properties, and setting this as the log configuration file in pom.xml (or better, just use logback instead of log4j, which is more flexible to configure -- but I digress)